# Dataset with informations about donations

Tags: data-request, finance, ngo

Somebody know if exists some dataset with informations about donations?

 Like, how many people donate and the frequency they do it.

Answer (score 5):

You can find aggregated data on charitable donations from the IRS's Statistics of Income (SOI). Here are some links to look around:

http://www.irs.gov/uac/Tax-Stats-2

http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-Statistics-of-Income

In the UK, the National Council for Voluntary Organisations (NCVO) and the Charities Aid Foundation (CAF), has been conducting and compiling survey results on charitable contributions by individuals. The data goes back to 2004:

http://data.ncvo.org.uk/datastore/datasets/dataset-6-uk-giving-survey/

Answer (score 2):

*Not a clear answer but I think this constitutes an answer with a few leads for you to follow. Anyone, please correct me if I'm wrong*

- I'd suggest you check out some sites like http://guidestar.org/ and http://nccs.urban.org/
- I think you'll need to scope your question further. You can also probably start to look at open data about IRS taxes as most people will want to take advantage of the tax deduction.
- See also http://www.taxpolicycenter.org/briefing-book/key-elements/exempt/who-benefits.cfm and associated data tables I think they'll have.

Comment: NCSS provides statistics on the charities (vs. donors)

Answer (score 1):

The information about who donates to a non-profit in the US is located on the Schedule B of the IRS 990 form.  This schedule is not public for exempt organizations, but it may be public for trusts and public foundations.  I suggest using guidestar.org (free registration) to search out the non-profits you're interested in.

If you are interested in bulk 990s for "free" (the data is free; the cost to get it packaged and mailed to you by the IRS is about $3,000/year I believe), you can find them here:
https://archive.org/details/IRS990

Comment: No need to pay for it ... resource.org buys it, then puts it up for people to download : https://bulk.resource.org/irs.gov/eo/readme.html